# Metadata Parameter IPN Support for Bluesnap Payments Page?

Tags: payment-gateway, webhooks, bluesnap

I see that you can pass custom key/value pairs i.e Metadata params in Bluesnap's Hosted Payments Page - https://support.bluesnap.com/docs/creating-a-hosted-payments-page

Are they sent back in the IPN webhook when a transaction is successfully processed? If not - what is the workaround so that I can update my back-end system with the parameters sent in the request?

Answer (score 0):

No, They are not sent back in the IPN webhook when a transaction is successfully processed.
workaround you can use Reporting API to fetch the metadata fields